# Regular Expression Extract string

Tags: regex

I have this expression

```
accordionMain_i0_accordion_i0_ctl01_0_ddl_xxxxxxxx_iy_tblItem
```

where xxx can contain also '_' and its number vary, and y start from 0 by incrementing. I would like to extract the xxxxxx using regular expression. I tried split function but the xxxx can contain several '_' , so by removing the last 2 element of the array from split I have to check for ddl, then join all part of xxx  etc. Do you know a better method by using REGEX? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a pro or anything... but if it were me I would split at "ddl_" and then read until I hit "_iy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you RegEx engine supports `lookahead` and `lookbehind`, then use:

```
(?<=_ddl_)\w+?(?=_i\d+)
```

else

```
(:_ddl_)(\w+?)(?:_i\d+)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex `accordionMain_i0_accordion_i0_ctl01_0_ddl_(.*?)_i\d+_tblItem` returns your **xxxxxxxx** if match found.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the language you're using.  But here's a stab at it:

```
/accordionMain_i0_accordion_i0_ctl01_0_ddl_([x_]+)_i\d+_tblItem/
```

Then, your x's will be stored in the first capture, `$1`.

Here is a demo: http://rubular.com/r/MH4GbMStdf.

**EDIT:**

If you meant "anything" instead of literal "x", then:

```
/accordionMain_i0_accordion_i0_ctl01_0_ddl_(.+)_i\d+_tblItem/
```